# Create Custom User Theme for Outlook Web App (OWA) in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

I am looking for a way to create a new custom theme that users can select from the settings menu in their mailbox:

[image: Change Theme]

So far I have found the following documentation: [Create a theme for OWA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201700%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)
However, it seems to be for Exchange 2010.

The documentation says I can find these themes in the following location:
\Client Access\OWA\version\Owa2\resources\themes

I can find \Client Access\OWA\version\Owa2 but there is no resources or theme directory in any of the versions folders (just ext and scripts folders):

[image: Version Folders] [image: Owa2] [image]

Does anyone know where the existing themes are stored?
How can I create my own theme or make changes to an existing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming here using google, the correct directory seems to be this directory:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\owa\prem\ [version]\resources\themes

The technet/Microsoft documentation specifies the wrong directory.

Answer (score -1):

This is the path:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth\15.0.847\themes\resources